# box-shadow on div with border-radius is slightly off center

Tags: css, border, radius

I am trying to animate a box shadow in CSS to display a contact image as rounded. When I hover over it, I want to show the picture as is, and with a circle of 1px where the previous shadow covered all the picture.

For this I have a div `<contact_image>` in which I have the persons image under the div `<person_img>` and a div that is positioned above the image with

```
z-index: 1200;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
border-radius: 100%;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 300px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 300px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 300px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

the border radius at the time is 300px which will cover all the image but no more, since the `contact_image` container has `overflow: hidden`

Now when I hover over the image, I want to shrink the box-shadow

to 1px:

```
.contact:hover .contact_image .contact_frame{
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: contact_image_circle;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}


    @keyframes contact_image_circle{
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 300px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    }
}
```

But as you can see in this fiddle the box shadow is slightly off-centered.
I`m experiencing this in Firefox, and IE.

**UPDATE:**

After playing around for a while I can now say, that this is definitely a Firefox issue (having ONE side of the round box-shadow a little bit bigger than the other). HOWEVER, I'm experiencing something similar when using IE (the shadow seems to be bigger on BOTH sides, and fine on top and bottom). In Chrome I am not able to reproduce this problem.

What is even more strange is, that I'm only having the issue in Firefox and IE when viewing the elements on my big monitor. On my laptop (higher resolution) everything is fine!

https://jsfiddle.net/29probgm/

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by off-centered? Do you mean that the circle itself is not vertically centered (more space on bottom than on top)?

Comment: @elveti No. as you can see in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/29probgm/ the circle that the box-shado should produce is not even on all sides.

Comment: @DigitalJedi Are you still experiencing this in all browsers?  I am encountering what I think is the same issue (off-center box-shadows on rounded elements), but I am only seeing the issue in Firefox - https://jsfiddle.net/fmvyroje/

Comment: Hi, firstoff, thx for your comment! After playing around for a while I can now say, that this is definitely a firefox issue (having ONE side of the round box-shadow a little bit bigger than the other). HOWEVER, Im experiencing something similar when using IE (the shadow seems to be bigger on BOTH sides, and fine on top and bottom). In Chrome I am not able to reproduce this problem anymore -> I will update my question. What is even more strange is, that Im only having the issue in Firefox and IE when viewing the elements on my big monitor, on my laptop (higher resolution) everything is fine!

Comment: I'm assuming this is some kind of browser rendering issue. If you find out anything about it I would be glad if you kept me up2date.

Comment: I'm experiencing this in Chrome.